# How I can remove Carousel from individual pages

Tags: php, html, css, carousel, master-pages

I put a carousel in **master.blade.php** and now I do not know how to remove it from some specific pages.

When I try with this code in my custom.css

```
#myCarousel {display: none;}
```

This code remove my carousel from all pages but I need from specific pages.

How I can do that?

Comment: You will have to find a way to control the content of individual pages. What more can I say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to remove spesific class or id from spesific page, you can use parent class or id name for it.

for example in a.html page

```
<div class="parentClass">
     <div id="myCarousel"></div>
</div>
```

and in b.html page

```
<div class="parenClassTwo">
     <div id="myCarousel"></div>
</div>
```

and you want to remove myCarousel from b.html page

then you can use this method

```
.parentClassTwo > #myCarousel {display: none;}
```